# Minimum Bandwidth Guarantee 3750-X

Tags: cisco-catalyst, qos, policing

I am about to implement a network at a remote office that will also be providing some bandwidth to a sub tenant. We have a 50 Mbps connection terminating to a VLAN on a 3750-X. Each company has an L2 handoff on the same VLAN. I want to shape traffic so that Client A is guaranteed around 30 Mbps, and Client B is guaranteed around 20 Mbps at maximum utilization. If, for example, Client A is using 1 Mbps, Client B should be able to use the rest of the available bandwidth until Client A needs more.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a spare 3750X to validate this with but I think I got it...

John Kennedy gave a great answer if you want to give a hard limit to the amount of traffic that Client A and B can send but your question was how to guarantee a minimum amount of bandwidth and still allow bursting if BW is available.

In order to accomplish this we will have a policer on each of the Client A and B ingress interfaces.  The set of policers will classify the traffic into 4-classes, Client-A conforming (the first 30Mb, set DSCP to AF31, decimal value 26), Client-A non-conforming (everything above 30Mb, set as DSCP AF32, decimal value 28), Client-B conforming (first 20Mb, DSCP AF21, 18), Client-B non-conforming (over 20Mb, set DSCP AF22, 20).

We will then map each of these classes to a queue on egress and allocate the bandwidth in a manner that should allow each client the minimum required bandwidth but still have the ability to use more if it is available.

first let's map dscp values (in decimal) to egress queues

```
mls qos srr-queue output dscp-map queue 1 threshold 1 26
mls qos srr-queue output dscp-map queue 2 threshold 1 18
mls qos srr-queue output dscp-map queue 3 threshold 1 28
mls qos srr-queue output dscp-map queue 4 threshold 1 20
```

then we create the map to change af31 to af32 and af21 to af22 when it exceeds the guaranteed rate

```
mls qos map policed-dscp 26 to 28
mls qos map policed-dscp 18 to 20
```

create a policy that sets the traffic to af31 for all traffic and if the traffic exceeds 30Mb then set to af32

```
policy-map reserve-30mb
 class-default
  set dscp 26
  police 30000000 exceed-action policed-dscp-transmit
```

create another policy that sets the traffic to af21 for all traffic and if the traffic exceeds 20Mb then set to af22

```
policy-map reserve-20mb
 class-default
  set dscp 18
  police 20000000 exceed-action policed-dscp-transmit
```

apply the policy to the client A input interface

```
interface GigabitEthernet 1/0/1
 service-policy input reserve-30mb
```

apply the policy to the client B input interface

```
interface GigabitEthernet 1/0/2
 service-policy input reserve-20mb
```

for the WAN interface we set the ratio to 60/40 on queue 1 & 2 (AF31 and AF21) and then set the overflow queues to small values so that they can share any remaining bandwidth

```
interface GigabitEthernet 1/0/3
 srr-queue bandwidth share 60 40 1 1
```

The only task this does not accomplish is limit the WAN bandwidth to 50Mb.
`srr-queue bandwidth limit` should do this, however the documentation says it only supports 10-90%.  If the link is FastEthernet you may be able to do this using `srr-queue bandwidth limit 50`

I pulled a lot of the configuration details from [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750x_3560x/software/release/12.2_55_se/configuration/guide/swqos.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you can do with a 3750:

```
class-map match-all CLIENT1
 match input-interface  GigabitEthernet1/0/1 (or match based off AN ACL for the client networks)
class-map match-all CLIENT2
 match input-interface  GigabitEthernet1/0/2 (or match based off AN ACL for the client networks)
!
policy-map BW
 class CLIENT1
  police 30000000 500000 exceed-action drop
 class CLIENT2
  police 20000000 400000 exceed-action drop
!
interface GigabitEthernet 1/0/1
 srr-queue bandwidth limit 3
!
interface GigabitEthernet 1/0/2
 srr-queue bandwidth limit 2
!
!
interface whatever your outbound L3 interface is
 service-policy input BW
```

This configuration gives you interface rate-limiting down to the desired bandwith (it is a percentage so 3= 30mbps on a GigE interface) and also checks the traffic being sent thru your outbound L3 interface to make sure that the traffic complies. By outbound L3 interface I am referring generically to whatever L3 gateway is shared by both clients whether it is an SVI (interface Vlan X) or your outbound physical interface.

Comment: Thank you both. I will try them out today and report back.